# Sklearn encoding on columns with multiple classes on same cell

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Let's suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
   Column
0  A - B - C
1      A - B
2      A - C
3          A
4          B
5          C
```

I want to encode the "Column" but I have multiple classes in the same cell. Using pandas I can do the following to get the proper encoding output:

`df['Column'].str.get_dummies(sep=' - ')`

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  0
2  1  0  1
3  1  0  0
4  0  1  0
5  0  0  1
```

How can I do the same transformation using Sklearn?

Comment: **One**-hot, by its name, implies that you only ever expect to have a **single** bit turned on, while the rest are zero. Your case isn't entirely that (rows can have occupancy across multiple features)

Comment: @ALollz: I understand, thank you. Do you know any other approach I can use with Sklearn to have the same results?

Comment: @ALollz: I found a way, updating the post with the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can do this with `CountVectorizer` specifying how you want to identify boundaries.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column': ['A - B - C', 'A - B', 'A - C', 'A', 'B', 'C']})    

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=lambda x: x.split(' - '))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Column'])
```

---

```
X.toarray()
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])

vectorizer.get_feature_names()
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use the MultiLabelBinarizer class as it supports an iterable as input.

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.split(' - ')
enc = MultiLabelBinarizer()
enc.fit_transform(df['Column'])
```